# Suppress dyld load messages

Tags: macos, dyld

I got a lot of messages below every time I invoke node or python commands. Anyone knows how to suppress these messages? It's kind of annoying.

```
::::::::
::::::::
dyld: loaded: <D32CC064-3983-3066-889F-37387DD7836E> /usr/local/bin/node
dyld: loaded: <9D772EFC-EBBE-3337-A7B5-606E63E561B7> /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.63.dylib
dyld: loaded: <DA3EFA7B-AA03-31D1-A474-90A419442B4E> /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicuuc.63.dylib
dyld: loaded: <0971BFB8-3B50-3E85-9514-0CC659954EFB> /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicudata.63.1.dylib
::::::::
```

Answer (score 1):

These messages indicate that the `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES` environment variable is set when you're running the commands in question. Unset that environment variable and the messages will stop.